# Listview перекрывает Toolbar

Tags: android, listview, android-sdk, android-toolbar

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.application.nikit.mydoctor.Activity.MedicamentActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_head"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_tablet_pager"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**content_tablet_pager.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.application.nikit.mydoctor.Activity.MedicamentActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_tablet_pager">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activity.MedicamentActivity"
        android:id="@+id/root">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/tablet_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/tablet_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MedicamentActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {


        private Fragment mCurrentFragment;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablet);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);

   ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);




    mCurrentFragment = new InfiniteHorizontalTabletFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, mCurrentFragment).commit();



    ButterKnife.bind(this);


}
```

Fragment для ViewPager

```
public class InfiniteHorizontalTabletFragment extends Fragment implements ViewFactory {

private int mBgColor;


final String[] tablet_name = new String[]{
        "Паратетамол", "Эспумизан", "Милдронат", "Фенибут",
        "Луналдин", "Анастезин", "Кадионат", "Триметазин",
        "Рибоксин", "Предуктал МВ", "Валидол", "Моносан"
};
final int[] count = {
        1, 1, 2, 2,
        2, 3, 1, 2,
        1, 1, 2, 3
};

final String[] time = new String[]{
        "8:20", "8:20", "8:40", "9:20",
        "10:10", "10:20", "11:05", "12:00",
        "13:00", "13:00", "15:40", "21:40"
};

final String[] time_check = new String[]{
        "8:25", "8:30", "8:40", "9:30",
        "10:25", "10:30", "11:25", "13:00",
        null, null, null, null
};





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.content_tablet_pager, container, false);
    ViewPager verticalPager = (ViewPager)layout.findViewById(R.id.tablet_view_pager);

    if(verticalPager.getParent()!=null)
        ((ViewGroup)verticalPager.getParent()).removeView(verticalPager); // <- fix

    verticalPager.setAdapter(new InfiniteHorizontalPagerAdapter(this, 0));
    verticalPager.setCurrentItem(Constants.START_INDEX);

    return verticalPager;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View makeView(int vertical, int horizontal) {
    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
    TabletArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new TabletArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
            tablet_name, count, time, time_check);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("Принять " + tablet_name[position-1] + "?")
                            .setConfirmText("Да")
                            .setCancelText("Пропустить")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                    sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }
            }
    );

    return listView;
  }
}
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: Из разметки фрагмента нужно убрать FrameLayout (сделать корневым ViewPager или заменить на LinearLayout,  если пэйджер не может быть корневым) , да и оборачивание ListView в LinearLayout лишнее

Comment: Я уже наверное все виды layout перепробовал. Не помогает.

Comment: Попробуйте создать новую `Activity` со стандартной разметкой. Если наползать на панель не будет, то проанализируйте различия в коде. Попробуйте привести Вашу разметку к первоначальному виду.

Comment: Корневым элементом для разметок с `AppBarLayout` должен быть `CoordinatorLayout`, а не `LinearLayout`. Смотртие хоть бы [этот пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android-support-design.php)

Comment: Создал новый проект добавил Viewpager и опять перекрывает

Answer (score 0):

Уберите в разметке у элемента `include` параметры `layout_width` и `layout_height`.

Он должен выглядеть так:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_tablet_pager" />
```

Тогда все станет на место.

Comment: Не помогло, всё как и прежде.